# Android Custom Spinner not Populating

Tags: android, string, fonts, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Having trouble getting my spinner to populate. Well, I was getting it to populate just fine with a string array from strings.xml but now I want to add a custom font to the array. I'm using a Custom ArrayAdapter for the first time and it is overwriting my "android:entries=" and "android:prompt=" inside its layout xml.

So, I need to populate this spinner with an array from my strings.xml

(Inside onCreate)

```
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distancespinner);
    MyArrayAdapter ma = new MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.my_spinner_style);
    spinner1.setAdapter(ma);
```

Then:

```
 private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/m01.TTF");  

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public TextView getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    v.setTypeface(font);
    return v;
    }

    public TextView getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    v.setTypeface(font);
    return v;
    }

    }
```

I tried adding the entries and prompt again inside the my_spinner_style.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/location_arrays"
android:prompt="@string/location_prompt"
android:singleLine="True" />
```

But, that is not working either.

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: There's no error message. Everything loads up just fine but the spinner is empty.

Comment: Set log.d to check is the spinner data is populating correctly or not.

Comment: i've only used log to check for variables: Log.i(TAG, "Var: " + myVariable I don't know how to use it to check a spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the code I rewrote and it's working fine:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distancespinner);
spinner.setPromptId(R.string.location_prompt);
MyArrayAdapter ma = new MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.my_spinner_style);
ma.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(
        R.array.location_arrays)));
spinner.setAdapter(ma);
```

And the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="True" />
```

`Adapter` is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a little late. After I implement your code and some additional test, I think  I finally get the answer. The KEY problem the spinner not populating is:

**You set the entries of the spinner within the xml file but replace it programmatically with an EMPTY adapter.**

I have tried the following ways to populate the spinner with different results:

1. Set the entries in xml without any adapter.

   ```
   <Spinner 
   android:id="@+id/simple_spinner2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/simpleStringArray"
   android:prompt="@string/simplePrompt"/>
   ```

   It populates the spinner with right content without any additional style.
2. Set the entries in xml with another adapter set to the spinner (as you did in the question)

   in .xml

   ```
   <Spinner 
   android:id="@+id/simple_spinner2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/simpleStringArray"
   android:prompt="@string/simplePrompt"/>
   ```

   in .java:

   ```
   Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simple_spinner2);
   MySpinnerAdapter2 spinnerAdapter2 = new MySpinnerAdapter2(this, R.layout.simple_list_item);
   ```

   It displays an empty spinner.
3. set the data programmatically to adapter

   in .xml

   in .java
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);

   ```
   Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simple_spinner2);
   MySpinnerAdapter2 spinnerAdapter2 = new MySpinnerAdapter2(this, R.layout.simple_list_item);
   spinnerAdapter2.addAll(items2);
   ```

   private class MySpinnerAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter {

   ```
   public MySpinnerAdapter2(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
       super(context, textViewResourceId);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       v.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
       return v;
   }

   @Override
   public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Igualb.ttf");
       TextView v = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
       v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       v.setTypeface(myFont);
       return v;
   }
   ```

It displays the content correctly with cumtom-set font.

You can check for the complete project in [this github repository](https://github.com/demote/androidTest/tree/master/DemoteAndroidTest) if you like to.

Wish this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be the below line is incorrect

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/m01.TTF");
```

`m01.TTF` is wrong change to `m01.ttf`

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/m01.ttf");
```

Comment: The font is loading correctly. I have other TextViews that use it. If I take all that code out then the Spinner populates just fine (because "entries=" and "prompt=" is set in the layout for the spinner). I'm looking for a way to populate the spinner, using code that works with what I have now.